# Do I need Vue.set() in order to change value of a data object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I understand that Vue.set() is used to add reactive properties to an object.

But how would I change the value of an object property. Is this the correct way?

***Note:*** ***This data change is intended to be sent to the database***

Template

```
 <div class="buttonList" v-for="(expense, index) in expenseButton" :key="index">
    <button type="button" @click="expenseButtonClick(expense)">{{expense.expensesKey}} </button>
    <input class="textInput" v-model.number="expense.subExpense" type="number" />
</div>
```

```
data(){
   expenseButton[{
expenseKey: rent,
expenseValue: 10,
subExpenses: ''
}]

}

methods: {
    expenseButtonClick(expense) {
      expense.expensesValue = expense.expensesValue - expense.subExpense;
      console.log(expense);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Vue.set` only when you need to add a new property to an object and want it to be reactive. You don't need it when changing an existing property's value.

FYI, you also need to use `Vue.delete` only when deleting a property from an object to ensure the view gets updated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So is the method that I am using a feasible way to initialize the new value?

Comment: If you're initializing it, then I'd suggest using `Vue.set`. If you're just updating it then what you're doing in the `expenseButtonClick` works.